# How do I extract a variable from an INSERT query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

This is for a registration form I have created. I cannot include all of my code, but the program checks for blank fields then format using the preg_match function. Then it INSERTS the info registered

My code is:

```
<?php
 /* connection info */
ini_set('include_path','../../includes');
include("dbinfo.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) 
    or die("Couldn't connect to server. error 3");
?>


<?php
/*  Program name: Register.php 
 *  Description:  Program displays the blank form and checks 
 *  all the form fields for blank fields.
 */


 // Insert info into database //
    {
    foreach($good_data as $field => $value)
        {
            $good_data[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$value);
        }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (user_id, password, first_name, last_name, city, country, email) VALUES ('$good_data[user_id]', '$good_data[password]', '$good_data[first_name]', '$good_data[last_name]', '$good_data[city]', '$good_data[country]', '$good_data[email]')";

        $result = mysqli_query($query, $sql) or die ("Couldn't connect to login");
        $row = mysqli_fetch($result);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $sql2 = "UPDATE TimeStamp SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where user_id='$good_data[user_id]'";  
               $result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql2) or die("<p>Couldn't Connect to Login</p>");
                       include('goodReg.inc');

        }
        {
            echo $message;
            extract($good_data);
            include('register.inc');
            exit();
        } 
    }   
}
else
{
  include("register.inc");
}
?>
```

How do I move just the variable to the query and not the whole INSERT string?

Comment: ummmmm..Thanks? I guess

Comment: You can't use `fetch` with an `INSERT` query, it doesn't return anything. What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to get the auto increment ID assigned to the new row, use `mysqli_insert_id($cxn)`.

Comment: the first die statement isn't really proper.  As Barmar said you aren't bringing back a result set to loop

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I wouldn't have known that I am still relatively new to this. I am trying to make it so that the insert query after it is executed and the information is put into the database it will display the goodReg.inc file. Which, simply states that their registration was Successful. Then update the TimeStamp database with the new username. I guess it should be mentioned that the username is hte unique key for the UserInfo database

Comment: You dont update a reserved word. You update a tablename. Start with a web tutorial

Comment: @DrewPierce I think `TimeStamp` is the name of his table, it has a column named `time`. `TimeStamp` is not a reserved word.

Comment: My people sure are being critical, is there a web tutorial you would recommend Drew? The UPDATE query is for the TimeStamp table in the Mysql database. I don't think that counts as a reserved word, but I could be wrong

Comment: Sorry @Barmar i guess i read this table wrong https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: You have an `else` statement with no matching `if`.

Comment: Just about any top google rank tutorial Jason. We are a jovial bunch, don't mean to be offensive. Kinda wry sense of humor

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to call `mysqli_fetch` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Just do the `UPDATE` query outside of a loop:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (user_id, password, first_name, last_name, city, country, email) VALUES ('$good_data[user_id]', '$good_data[password]', '$good_data[first_name]', '$good_data[last_name]', '$good_data[city]', '$good_data[country]', '$good_data[email]')";
mysqli_query($cxn, $sql) or die ("Couldn't insert into UserInfo: " . mysqli_error($cxn));

$sql2 = "UPDATE TimeStamp SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where user_id='$good_data[user_id]'";  
mysqli_query($cxn, $sql2) or die ("Couldn't update TimeStamp: " . mysqli_error($cxn);

include('goodReg.inc');
```